# What's Wrong? Nothing Will Load (Almost)!

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay...My title is a bit of an exaggeration...

My site is built in PHP, and all the files I'm trying to "require_once" aren't being loaded.  The only file I've changed is my .htaccess file.  I don't know a thing about .htaccess and what I have is purely from searching the web.  What is wrong?  Thanks for any help in advance.

```
RewriteEngine on

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
ReWriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ReWriteRule !index.php index.php [L]
```

Also, if I comment out the bottom two lines, my site works great.

Comment: Was your site working before?

Comment: Well, if you comment out the last two lines and it works, then it will have something to do with those last two lines in the .htaccess file

Comment: I'm no master with them unfortunately, but you should really learn how the code works/what it does before copy-pasting (I'm presuming this is what you have done)

Comment: Yes, it was working perfectly before.  And, yes, I know Sean (Not being rude), but I don't know anything about htaccess...So that's why I came here.  :P

Comment: I didn't just copy and paste, I got the basic idea of what I was doing (or at least I thought I did) and changed the lines to work with my file system.

Comment: Ok ok, fair enough, me making bad assumptions! I'm pretty sure those last two lines are attempting to redirect you to the index page regardless of what your current page is

Comment: Unfortunately those last two lines look like double dutch to me :( it might be best trying to edit your answer to include any error messages you get when trying to load the page; then hoping someone with more knowledge comes along. Sorry I'm not of much help here!

Comment: That is the idea.  I want to redirect to the index.php page so that it can load the other page dynamically with AJAX into the content without changing the URL.  And it is redirecting to the index.php page...What it isn't doing is letting jQuery, PHP, or any other kind of language access any pages outside of it (such as I can't get my CSS to load, nor my require_once, nor my AJAX, or anything of the sort).

Comment: Oh I see, that makes a lot of sense, I wonder if there's a way to exclude IP addresses (say exclude your servers IP address) from those last two lines of rules

Comment: Maybe this is helpful? http://www.webdesignlondon-tristar.co.uk/general/htaccess-redirect-all-users-except-your-ip

Comment: How would I do that?  And sounds like a good idea (If I understand you correctly)!

Comment: Try using the code in my answer, hopefully I've gotten it right!

Comment: Sadly it doesn't appear to be working when I change it to the server's IP...

Comment: Try adding this code just before the last two lines:

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: That fixed the loading problem, but now it won't redirect.

Comment: Have a look here, hopefully this will sort it out: http://jrgns.net/content/redirect_request_to_index

Comment: You might also want to try getting rid of the "ReWriteBase /" line in your code

Comment: I got rid of that line...Still not redirecting...

Comment: Ok, I've made another edit to my answer, hopefully that helps. I've got to dash though, so if it doesn't help my recommendation would be coming back to it later, sometimes a fresh mind helps a lot when trying to solve problems.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `require_once` has nothing to do with `.htaccess` file: it's a PHP directive, not an Apache one. You have to set correctly the [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) for your files *and* make sure these directories and files are reachable (i.e., with correct privileges set on them).

If you show the error message you got from failed `require`, it'd be much more simple to give you a specific advice on how to fix it.

**UPDATE** If what you need is redirecting all the non-AJAX requests for .php files into `index.php`, your `.htaccess` should like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-requested-with} ^XMLHttpRequest$
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ReWriteRule .php$ index.php
```

This basically means the following: "all AJAX requests - go for what you need, all non-AJAX requests IF you're not going for some directory and are ended with .php - go for index.php instead".

Without checking for .php (or some similar check) you will redirect to `index.php` all the script loading procedures; and, unless you do it from some external CDN, it's not what would work in your case. )

Comment: With these two lines you redirect all requests for non-directories to `index.php` file, effectively losing the data in these requests. Perhaps it should be `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?query=($1) [L]`, at least? It's really hard to tell without seeing both error messages and index.php basic structure.

Comment: There are no error messages and the index.php's basic structure can be summed up as follows:

<html>
<head>
<script>
//Javascript stuff to use AJAX to load requested page's content
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<!--This is where the content goes-->
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Ok, so you need all your non-AJAX requests to be redirected to `index.php`, but AJAX requests to go through? Add this line to your `.htaccess` file then: `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH:%{HTTP:X-Requested-With}]`

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to do.  However...When I added that line, it didn't fix anything.  Does the fact I'm using jQuery for AJAX instead JavaScript affect anything?

Comment: No, the AJAX requests are still going with `X-Requested-With` header. Did you add this line before of after `index.php` RewriteRule?

Comment: I tried adding it both above and below.  Was it supposed to be above any other line?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last two lines to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

If you want your URL's to look something like this (you probably do):

```
http://yoursite.com/some/path/somewhere
```

then change the last line to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ index.php?first=$1&second=$2
```

If that's what you want to achieve, ensure that if you're trying to go to:

```
http://yoursite.com/about
```

That there isn't actually a folder called about, this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Checks to see if a folder with the name "about" exists, if it does, then the page will not redirect, the same goes for files, say you go to:

```
http://yoursite.com/about.html
```

If about.html actually exists then the page will not redirect.

Hope that makes sense.

If you need more information, http://jrgns.net/content/redirect_request_to_index seems to be fairly succinct and helpful.